# How to sort & group by sql query?

Tags: mysql

I have Data

```
id Date      CatId  itemid itemname price
1  10/5/2019  1         1      ABC        20
2  10/5/2019  1         2      XYZ        30
3  10/5/2019  2         1      ABC        20
4  10/5/2019  3         1      ABC        20  

5  11/5/2019  1         2      XYZ        30
6  11/5/2019  2         1      ABC        20
7  11/5/2019  2         3      PQR        40

8  12/5/2019  3         1      ABC        20
9  12/5/2019  3         2      XYZ        30 
10  12/5/2019  1         2      XYZ        30
11  12/5/2019  2         1      ABC        20
```

expected result data

```
date            CatId   toal 
 10/5/2019      1           50
 10/5/2019      2           20
 10/5/2019      3           20

  11/5/2019     1       30
  11/5/2019     2       60
  12/5/2019     1       30
  12/5/2019     2       20
  12/5/2019     3       50
```

I want result order by date and after sum of price group by catid,

I have tried multiple query applied but get exact solution. I have spent so much time.

I have tried bellow queries

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `table`  ORDER BY `date` DESC) as tbl
 GROUP BY tbl.`catid`
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `table`  
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
) AS sub
GROUP BY `catid` ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the columns you can use in order by and group by can be different

You could use group by and sum directly

```
select date, catid, sum(price)
from my_table 
group by date, catid
order by date, sum(price), catid
```

Comment: Thanks. You save my time